# Difficulty in understanding the sentence

Tags: translation

I translate games into my native language and am currently working on a new project and have difficulty understanding a certain sentence. The sentence is:

> Anyway, there's always more eggs to crack somewhere - heck, if you squeeze enough chickens into a small enough cage who knows what'll happen?

The problem concerns the phrase "there's always more eggs to crack". I guess that's some kind of idiom, but it doesn't make sense to me. An additional difficulty is the fact that the text is loosely scattered throughout the file and is not related to each other in any way, so it is difficult for me to grasp the context of the statement.

Would someone be so kind as to help me understand the meaning of this sentence?

Comment: It is not an idiom I recognise. _Cracking an egg_ presumably refers to breaking open an egg to for cooking. Without context, I have no idea what the writer is trying to say.

Comment: It might mean that there are always more opportunities / chances to achieve a purpose. But that's a guess only. And it's impossible to know how the first metaphor relates to the second about chickens. Unless there are other clues in the game, I doubt you'll find an answer.

Comment: I wonder if the author was trying to make a reference to the idiom [**you can't make an omelette without breaking eggs**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/you-can-t-make-an-omelette-without-breaking-eggs).  But I still don't understand the second sentence.

Comment: @stangdon I think this idiom fits my case perfectly - I forgot about it completely :) Thanks!